# Selenium unable to switch to TinyMCE iframe in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: python, internet-explorer-9, tinymce, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to swtich to an iframe in IE9 so I can `send_keys()` to the text area. When I do switch, I can tell that the webdriver thinks it switched (when I print `page_source`, it's right) but the cursor is still blinking on another textfield (not TinyMCE), at this point, if I send keys, the keys get appended to the other textfield and not to TinyMCE.

So I've been trying workarounds, If I select the the tinyMCE iframe and `click()`, the cursor is in the right place and I can send keys but the I can't return (switch back to the original frame/window) to submit the input.

Has anyone else run into this in IE9, are there workarounds?

This works, in Firefox and Chrome, just not IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem like this once, and its quite complicated to work around it since TinyMCE generates some dynamic content. What I ended up doing to manipulate the contents of the TinyMCE editor was calling the API directly via  `page.execute_script` and just doing it all on JavaScript.

A sample of my JS code is:

```
    jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().setContent('test text in editor');   
    jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().selection.select(jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().dom.select('p')[0]);
    jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('Italic','true');
    jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('Underline','true');  
    jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('Bold','true');
```

The first line adds text in TinyMCE's textarea, the second selects it (simulating a user cursor select), the third, fourth and fifth just manipulate the controls.

`.execCommand()` was particularly useful for activating the different extensions. After that I just validated that the form fields I was using were set with the expected HTML tags and called it a day.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I was trying to avoid the js solution but I don't think there's any way around it. I actually ended up using: tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>text to input</p>');